# Change markup of single form field

Tags: theming, entities

I have constructed a form manually using the Form API. I have one field in particular that needs to have it's markup changed a tad.

The #prefix/#suffix output should come immediately before/after the input control. I think the output currently looks like:

Can I override the themeing for a single field using something like:

```
$form['control'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'control_field',
  '#title' => 'Some title',
  '#type' => 'textfield'
);
```

Do I then implement MYTHEME_custom_theme in the templates.php???

Do you know of any exmaples I might use?

I tried adding:

```
function theme_control_field($variables) {

}
```

This did not seem to work...also I need control over all the markup for this field not just the field control but I need to relocate the prefix/suffix output as well!?!

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Did you clear the cache first? I believe you need to do so when new functions are added to a module or theme.

Comment: I did yes...

I don't understand why only the <input> element is removed when I add the '#theme' element to $form array -- I assumed the whole thing would be blanked (prefix, suffixe, title, description, etc) but those seem to still render -- just without the <input>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a complete custom HTML for a particular field by defining a `#theme` and setting `#theme_wrappers` with an empty value.

```
$form['control'] = array(
  '#title' => 'Some title',
  '#type' => 'textfield'
  '#theme' => 'YOURMODULE_control_field',
  '#theme_wrappers => array(),
);
```

Then Drupal needs to know about this new theme by implementing the `HOOK_theme`. You can either work with a template file or generate the HTML within the `theme` callback function

```
function YOURMODULE_theme()
{
    return array(
        'YOURMODULE_control_field' => array(
            'template' => 'templates/control-field', // if you want to have a tpl file, templates/control-field.tpl.php using the $element variable for your textfield element
            'render element' => 'element',
        ),
    );
}

// If you dont want to use the template file
function theme_YOURMODULE_control_field($variables)
{
    $element = $variables['element'];
    // $element is here your form textfield element, this function return HTML to generate
}
```

Comment: Excellent...I managed to achieve my desired effect by hooking MYTHEME_form_element() changing the markup on that one field and using default rendering on others but I still wanted to know how the above was possible so much appreciated. :)